# rounding decimal number in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line in code :

```
Avr_Hold_Time = (g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("QueueHoldCount")) == 0) 
                ? 0 
                : (double)(g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("Avr_Hold_Time"))) 
                  / (g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("QueueHoldCount")),
```

Which gives me floating number like 91.455678
I need to round up only 2 decimal after the point that rounds up after 3rd decimal number (e.g. 91.46)
how can I do that ?

Comment: Did you google at all before asking this question? This is not even linq. It's basic c#.

Comment: I did . I know it sounds stupid but I'm getting error Cannot convert double?  to double .

Comment: Issue solved I added <float> after / sign ..

Answer (score 2):

Use [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
decimal num = 91.455678m;
var rounded = Math.Round(num, 2); // 91.46
```

Comment: Yes but where do I put the Math Round in mu line ? like this : Math.Round((double)(g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("Avr_Hold_Time"))) / (g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("QueueHoldCount"))),2),